# ¿Cómo sumas varios inputs de forma automática con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo varios `input` en `HTML` que tienen valores numéricos de la base de datos en lenguaje `PHP` y un `input` al final que debería imprimir el valor de los `inputs` sumados, quiero que sumen los valores de los `inputs` con `javascript` sin necesidad del `onkeyup` y cuando cargue la pagina.

```js
function sum() {
            var acarreo = document.getElementById('acarreo[]').value;
            var pagocond = document.getElementById('pagocond[]').value;
   var via = document.getElementById('via[]').value;
   var peaje = document.getElementById('peaje[]').value;
   var combust = document.getElementById('combust[]').value;
            var result = parseFloat(acarreo)-( parseFloat(pagocond)+ parseFloat(via)+ parseFloat(peaje)+ parseFloat(combust));
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
            }
   }
```

```html
    <td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="acarreo[]" id="acarreo[]" value="<?php echo $acarreo=$row['acarreo']?>" title="ACARREO"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="pagocond[]" id="pagocond[]" value="<?php echo $pagocond=$row['pagocond']?>" title="PAGO DE CONDUCTOR"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="via[]"  id="via[]" value="<?php echo $via=$row['via']?>" title="VIATICO"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="peaje[]" id="peaje[]" value="<?php echo $peaje=$row['peaje']?>" title="PEAJE"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="combust[]" id="combust[]" value="<?php echo $combust=$row['combust']?>" title="COMBUSTIBLE"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txt3"  readonly/></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas llamar a la función `sum` al momento de cargar la página, eso lo puedes hacer definiendo `window.onload` como se ve a continuación:

```js
function sum() {
    var acarreo = document.getElementById('acarreo[]').value;
    var pagocond = document.getElementById('pagocond[]').value;
    var via = document.getElementById('via[]').value;
    var peaje = document.getElementById('peaje[]').value;
    var combust = document.getElementById('combust[]').value;

    var result = parseFloat(acarreo) - (parseFloat(pagocond) + parseFloat(via) + parseFloat(peaje) + parseFloat(combust));
    
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    sum();
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="acarreo[]" id="acarreo[]" value="1" title="ACARREO"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="pagocond[]" id="pagocond[]" value="2" title="PAGO DE CONDUCTOR"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="via[]"  id="via[]" value="3" title="VIATICO"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="peaje[]" id="peaje[]" value="4" title="PEAJE"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="5" onkeyup="sum();" name="combust[]" id="combust[]" value="5" title="COMBUSTIBLE"></td>

<td><input type="text" id="txt3"  readonly/></td>
```

Comment: Gracias saul...

Comment: Que tal Saúl, te agradezco que me respondas esta pregunta  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314442/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-sumar-valores-de-textbox-de-una-fila-incrementables/314446#314446