# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores de textbox de una fila incrementables?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente código que me permite sumar los campos de una fila y tambien me permite incrementar o añadir otra fila, **el problema es que no me permite sumar las otras filas.** cuando las añado o incremento mediante el botton add row.
He aquí el código:

**Este es el código para agregar mas filas:**

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

   var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

   for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
     case "text":
       newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
       break;
     case "checkbox":
       newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
       break;
     case "select-one":
       newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
       break;
    }
   }
  }

  function deleteRow(tableID) {
   try {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;

   for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
     if(rowCount <= 1) {
      alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
      break;
     }
     table.deleteRow(i);
     rowCount--;
     i--;
    }


   }
   }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
   }
  }
```

**Este es el código para sumar los campos de una fila:**

```js
function sum(e) {
    
    const tr = e.path[2]; // Accedemos a la fila de la tabla. El valor 2 debera ser cambiado dependiendo de la posicion del elemento tr en el objeto path.
    
    let total = 0; // contador

    tr.querySelectorAll('input:not(.txt3):not(.check)').forEach(el => {
     total += parseFloat(el.value);
    }); // Sumamos el value de todos los inputs de entrada de la fila
    
    tr.querySelector('.txt3').value = total; // Grabamos el valor total en el input de salida de la fila
}

 window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.txt3):not(.check)').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('input', sum);
    }); // Añadimos el evento sum a todos los inputs salvo el de salida

}
```

**Y este es el HTML:**

```html
<BODY>
 <form method="post" action="row2.php" autocomplete="off">
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <TR>
  <TD><INPUT type="text" class="check"  placeholder="not" />
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt[]"/></TD>
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt1[]"/></TD>
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt2[]"/></TD>
   <TD><INPUT type="text" class="txt3" placeholder="Resultado aqui" readonly/>
   
   
   </TD>
   
  </TR>

 <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
```

En resumen, solo quiero que sumen los demás campos mientras incremento las filas:                                                               /

Answer (score 0):

como tienes el evento de sum en el window load, cuando agregas una nueva fila
estos no está en el DOM en ese momento, lo que debes hacer es en el addRow lanzar
nuevamente el evento de suma para que tome los nuevos campos así:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }

        // AQUÍ AGREGAS EL EVENTO NUEVAMENTE
        document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.txt3):not(.check)').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('input', sum);
    });
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: podrías colocar el código entero? tengo nulo conocimiento en javascript y cuando lo coloco no se ejecuta bien

Comment: Mas o menos como explica la respuesta de aquí  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830262/how-to-automatically-sum-input-value-boxes-on-each-row-in-a-html-table